# React Js front end and Express backend - can't load static files properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a React app on front end. Here is the routes:

```
    var React = require("react");
    var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
    var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory} = require("react-router");
    var Main = require("Main");
    var BlogList = require('BlogList');
    var Blogpost = require('Blogpost');
    var NewBlog = require('NewBlog');
    var EditBlog = require('EditBlog');
    var NotFound404 = require('NotFound404');


    ReactDOM.render(    
        <Router history={browserHistory}>   
            <Route path="/" component={Main}>
                <IndexRoute component={BlogList} />     
                <Route path="blogs/new" component={NewBlog} />          
                <Route path="blogs/:id/edit" component={EditBlog} />                        
                <Route path="blogs/:id" component={Blogpost} /> 
                <Route path='404' component={NotFound404} />
                <Route path='*' component={NotFound404} />          
            </Route>        
        </Router>, 

        document.getElementById("app")
    );
```

and here is index.html from `public` directory:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>     
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/app.css">
        <title>MERN Blog</title>
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

My express backend:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

.....

//index route
app.get("/api/blogs", function(request, response){      
...
});
//show route
app.get("/api/blogs/:id", function(request, response){      
...
});

app.get('*', function (request, response){  
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});
```

All works fine when I click links - all renders correct.
But when I refresh the same page - I got blank page.
My index.html loads some files - bundle.js etc. And those requests are handled by "*" route from backend - and index.html is alwas returned.

---

How to make static files handled properly?

Comment: Try putting everything else (like images, css...) under a static path... like `/static` and create a route to that, so the browser can find those resources

Comment: Is the issue that static files aren't showing up or that when you refresh a route it doesn't show up correctly?

Comment: @BradBumbalough - the problem is - when I load index.html - it makes requests to my backend for bundle.js file. It must be handled by app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  but instead it's handled by  app.get('*' ...

Comment: @LucasKatayama I get your idea. Thank you. It could be considered as a solution I think. But for what I am using app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));   So it means I dont need it anymore?

Comment: Oh NOW I get the problem... your are using relative paths... when you calll ./stylesheets/ when you refresh a page inside say /react-route/X.... it will call /react-router/X/stylesheet.... Try using absolute path so it can be handled by express.static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using absolute paths in the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/app.css">
    <title>MERN Blog</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem using **relative paths** and **browserHistory** occurs when you refresh a page in path like **/route/x/y/z** and it loads index.html then it tries to load relative css (for instance) **/route/x/y/z/stylesheets/app.css**

When you use absolute paths it will be handled by your express.static

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It will load index.html and tries to load /stylesheets/app.css which will be handled correctly... like this

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
...
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe you have the correct solution! Mine was more for absolute paths in the local server directory.

Comment: Traditionally I think people use `/public` for the static files... either way it's irrelevant without the absolute paths.